# Is it normal to suffer a heart attack out of fear from Allah? Is it normal to suffer anxiety disorder out of fear from Allah?

Tags: fiqh, sunni, sunnah, fear

Salaam aleikum.

Fear in this world produces suffering and pain and it poisons you both spiritually and physically (science has shown the bad effects of stress and anxiety on human body) because it is normal that when you fear something, you are in anxiety about the bad things that might happen, your heart may beat stronger, you feel less pleasure from the things around you.

My Question is:
Does the fear towards god produce all the above mentioned effects in the beginning like all other fears do, and latter as a result of refraining from sins and doing larg quantities of good deeds(as a result of this fear) it produces good feelings of love for Allah, and many other good feelings but < only later as a reward from Allah just like the rewards of paradise that comes later>?

Is it a fear that unlike other fears that cause suffering to the body, it is a fear that produces only pleasure every time it is present in the body? Is it normal to suffer a heart attach out of fear from Allah?

Is it normal to suffer anxiety disorder out of fear from Allah?

Comment: If a person only has fear of Allah rather than fear, love, and hope it is possible that it might happen.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing lexical meanings of fear and heart with their intended allegorical meanings.  When you allegorically 'fear' Allah, you are in fact alleviating actual physical fears and anxieties.  This is because you surrender your will to your creator and sustainer and live your life and make decisions in accord with the messenger's prescriptions.  By 'fearing' Allah, you are healing both your spiritual heart and the physical.